# What am I doing wrong when testing for concavity with $f(x)=5x^{2/3}-2x^{5/3}$?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong when testing for concavity with $f(x)=5x^{2/3}-2x^{5/3}$. I can't find the right intervals for where the graph is concave-down and concave-up.

---

**My Steps:**

find $f'(x)$:

$$f'(x)=\frac{10}{3}x^{-1/3}-\frac{10}{3}x^{2/3}=\frac{10}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}-\frac{10\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{3}$$

find $f''(x)$:

$$\frac{d}{dx} 3\sqrt[3]{x} = 0 + \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}} \cdot 3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{10}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}=\frac{0-[\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}} \cdot 10]}{(3\sqrt[3]{x})^2}=\frac{-10}{(3\sqrt[3]{x})^2(\sqrt[3]{x^2})}=\frac{-10}{9\sqrt[3]{x^4}}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}10\sqrt[3]{x^2}= 0 +10 \cdot \frac{d}{dx}x^{2/3}=\frac{10}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{10\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{3}=\frac{0 - [\frac{10}{3\sqrt[3]{x}} \cdot 3]}{9} = \frac{-30}{9(3\sqrt[3]{x})}=\frac{-10}{9\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

$$f''(x)=-\frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{x^4}}-\frac{-10}{9\sqrt[3]{x}}= \frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{x}}-\frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{x^4}}$$

set $f''(x) = 0$ and solve for $x$.

$$\frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{x}}-\frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{x^4}}=0 \to x=1$$

find $f''(-1)$.

$$\frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{(-1)}}-\frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{(-1)^4}}=\frac{-20}{9}$$

find $f''(2)$

$$\frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{(2)}}-\frac{10}{9\sqrt[3]{(2)^4}}=\frac{5\sqrt[3]{4}}{18}$$

So the graph should be concave-down on $(-\infty, 1)$ and concave-up on $(1, \infty)$.

However, this is wrong.

Comment: Just the first error I spotted: it seems like it should be $$f''(x)=-\frac{10}{9}x^{-4/3}-\frac{20}{9}x^{-1/3}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit easier if you factor out the smallest fractional power of $x$ at each step.

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&5x^{2/3}-2x^{5/3}=x^{2/3}(5-2x)\\
f^\prime(x)&=&\frac{10}{3}x^{-1/3}-\frac{10}{3}x^{2/3}=\frac{10}{3}x^{-1/3}(1-x)\\
f^{\prime\prime}(x)&=&-\frac{10}{9}x^{-4/3}-\frac{20}{9}x^{-1/3}=-\frac{10}{9}x^{-4/3}(1+2x)
\end{eqnarray}

**ADDENDUM:**
Note that since $f^\prime(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$ and $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=0$ at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ you should check the concavity on the intervals $\left(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}\right)$, $\left(-\frac{1}{2},0\right)$ and $(0,\infty)$

Here is the graph with the visually indiscernible inflection at $\left(-\frac{1}{2}, 3\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$.

[image: graph of equation]

Comment: Thank you, is there a post somewhere that will tell me how to display graphs here, or is that a screenshot?

Comment: This is a screenshot from [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Answer (score 2):

Keep going with fractional exponents, it's much easier:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{10}{3}x^{-1/3}-\frac{10}{3}x^{2/3}
$$
Therefore
$$
f''(x)=-\frac{10}{9}x^{-4/3}-\frac{20}{9}x^{-1/3}=-\frac{10}{9}x^{-1/3}(x^{-1}-2)
$$
This is undefined for $x=0$, and it should be easy study the sign elsewhere.